# How come my rep changed today?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I could not believe yesterday night when I went to sleep my rep was at 2.10AM(IST) 1979 and now today at 9.05AM(IST) it is 1861, like anybody has brought me into past when my rep was 1861. What kind of wired bug is this? I also gained moderators tool privilege, but can't see now it in my profile. What in name of God happened to my reputation? I also could not observe any downvote in my reputation changes recently. The recent rep change in my profile happened on probably 25th or 26th December i.e. acceptance of my answers to 2 questions. Moderators please have a look into this issue.

Comment: I have only two things to say. 1) Go to bed earlier. 2) Don't memorize your rep score.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini, Thanks for the suggestions. They are very wise indeed.

Answer (score 3):

I went through and deleted posts that had been closed for more than a month.  This has a negative side effect that some people's rep will change.  It's sort of a trade off, less closed questions clogging the site, but individual user reps are affected.  I lost about 50-100 rep myself this cleaning.

If you feel that one of your questions that was deleted should be reopened, you should be able to vote/flag for it to be reopened/undeleted.

Comment: I am sure deleted questions can be opened and it has been discussed in meta why should we keep closed questions.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149544/why-wait-to-delete-a-question-after-it-is-closed
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158984/answer-a-question-then-closed-because-off-topic-delete-my-answer

Comment: No I could not find any question of mine got deleted. Two of my answers got deleted of which I believe the answer on Avengers was really great and as the question has a good answer it should be undeleted.

Comment: On the second meta post you linked to, the accepted answer is more how I lean when it comes to excellent answers on junk questions.  If we leave it up we encourage more of those questions.

Comment: Anyways what about undeleting the answer I was pointing to...???

Comment: if it's the answer on why Avengers was so well recepted, I can't without undeleting the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. From this [view](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/3271/mistu4u?tab=reputation), I came to know some posts were removed. That is why the reps changed today. Anyways bad luck to me because they were most advantageous posts for my profiles. But I am sure I will be able to gain good reps soon. :)